Server calls from Android app on Google Play not executing
In my Android app written in Dart, I make calls for images to my node.js server. These calls have not been working now, and I am unable to determine why (they worked in the past).
NOTE: when I make these calls from a browser or from Postman, or have an associate call from outside my development lab, they work. In my app, however, when I click on a node to get another image, this fails, even when I completely hardcode the call without using any variables. ONLY in my app.
Format for each call:
https://www.myserver.com:4000/books
I am truly stuck and need some suggestions.
-David
In Dart, I build the calls I make using variables, but to eliminate this possibility I have hardcoded test calls to my server, like ones I make in Postman. When I upload the app to Google Play, I expect the calls to succeed, but they in fact fail.
I am confident that DNS on goDaddy is working correctly, and that my Edge router is allowing calls to my port (4000) through to my server, as confirmed by making calls to the server from sources other than my Google app.
